# UnhadledPromiseRejectionwarning: TypeError: Cannot read property " id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm trying to get a reference of resort in room but i got this error

[route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjRnf.png)

[model room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz8kp.png)

[roomPost controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii5cb.png)

[postman data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di5jP.png)

[**response**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44s7N.png)

[roomGet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wplwu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is how you parse the request.
Try with
"req.body.resort", in your postman screen, the resort is a string and not an object.